# Solving Poisson's Equation in 1-D for a point charge?

Tags: integration

Ok so I was trying to solve the Poisson's equation for a point charge with a Fourier transform to get the familiar equation.

This is what I did so far:

So ultimately I am trying to solve this in 3 dimensions but I am embarrassingly struggling with the 1-D solution right now.

$\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}}   f(x) = \rho(x) $

I express f and ρ in terms of their Fourier transforms:

$f(x) = \frac{1}{ \sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(\vec{k})e^{i \vec{k}\vec{x}}dk$

and

$\rho(x) = \frac{1}{ \sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\rho(\vec{k})e^{i \vec{k}\vec{x}} dk$

So from here I bring the derivative into the integral that is $f(x)$ and operate on the $e^{i \vec{k}\vec{x}}$ term:

$\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}}   f(x) = \frac{1}{ \sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} -k^{2} f(\vec{k})e^{i \vec{k}\vec{x}}dk$

I have:

$\frac{1}{ \sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} -k^{2} f(\vec{k})e^{i \vec{k}\vec{x}}dk = \frac{1}{ \sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\rho(\vec{k})e^{i \vec{k}\vec{x}} dk$

And I am able to drop the integrals because the Fourier transform is unique.

$-k^{2}f(\vec{k}) = \rho(\vec{k})$

So Now I can solve for $f(x)$:

$f(\vec{k}) = \frac{\rho(\vec{k})}{-k^2}$

So now for a point charge I know that $\rho(x) = q \delta(x)$ which will leave me with the following result when i try to use Fourier transforms to transform $f(\vec{k})$ back to $f(\vec{x})$:

$f(\vec{x}) = \frac{-1}{2 \pi} \frac{q}{\epsilon_o} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{k^2}e^{i \vec{k}\vec{x}}dk $

However I do not know how to integrate this to find the answer back in x-space. Have I went wrong somewhere or is their a certain trick to this integral?

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a maths question. You're working is mostly fine (see below), but Fourier transforms are a sledgehammer to crack a nut here: moreover, you need to be comfortable with tempered distributions if you use them in a problem like this.

The calculation you have done is for a *particular integral* of the linear equation $\mathrm{d}_x^2 f(x) = \rho(x)$ (I'll absorb the electric constant into $\rho$ hereafter). Your working is pretty much OK, aside from the fact that you've written a couple of equations with a Fourier transform on one side and an untransformed function on the other. The scale factor of $2\,\pi$ in the last line: you don't pick up a factor of $2\,\pi$ if you work through carefully.

Having found a PI, you need to understand that you can add any solution of the form $\mathrm{d}_x^2 f(x)=0$ to it and still have a solution. Here you can add any solution of the form $f(x) = A\,x + B$ where $A$ and $B$ are integration constants to be fixed by boundary conditions/ initial values.

The particular integral when $\rho$ is the distribution $\delta$ is the distribution given by the double integral of $\delta$, the integral of a step function namely the ramp:

$$f_0:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R};\;f_0(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}0;&x<0\\x;&x\geq0\end{array}\right.$$

So adding the PI we get:

$$f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R};\;f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}A\,x+B;&x<0\\(A+1)\,x+B;& x\geq0\end{array}\right.$$

and now we must add restrictions / use our physical intuition. You're solving for a potential, so we can add an arbitrary constant to the solution: offsets are a global gauge symmetry. Hence, you cannot hope to determine $B$, *any* real $B$ implies the same physics. For $A$, note that your problem corresponds to an infinite sheet of charge: the electric field will be constant and pointing in the $-x$ direction for $x<0$ and it will have the same magnitude but point in the opposite direction for $x>0$. This symmetry lets you find $A$.